# Convert fold -w 20 -s slash1.txt to python equivalent

Tags: python

I want to turn an 80 character line into 4 lines of 20 characters with word wrap. The original could be less that 80 characters, but more than 20. Bash fold works fine. Need answer for Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
% cat /tmp/out
The observation of the numerous misfortunes that attend all conditions forbids

% fold -w20 -s /tmp/out
The observation of 
the numerous 
misfortunes that 
attend all 
conditions forbids
```

A rough equivalent of `fold` in Python is [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill):

```
import textwrap
with open('/tmp/out', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
    result = textwrap.fill(content, width=20)
    print(result)
```

which prints

```
The observation of
the numerous
misfortunes that
attend all
conditions forbids
```

Comment: Just back from my walk. I'll try it and get back. Thanks!

Comment: Your helpful code appreciated. Need to a lot more Python!

Comment: I now really want to do this. Not do the print(result). Convert each 20 or less character line to an element of an array. Like:   line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4] These elements will be drawn on a very small OLED display, one line at a time. I can do that part.

Comment: I'll delete this comment and open a new question

Comment: @donde: In that case, use [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) instead of `textwrap.fill`. `textwap.wrap` returns a list of substrings, whereas `textwap.fill` returns one formatted string.

Comment: I'll try what you say.

Comment: Already using textwrap.wrap and getting 4 short strings. Now I would like a string array of these strings.

Comment: Hm, maybe it would be better that ask that as a new question.